# Fastest weight of gaining mass

Tags: weight-gain

What determines the best way of gaining muscles?
Is it necessary to keep low on fat while high on proteins? I have heard fats help in building new muscles.

Are mass gainers really effective?
How are they different from usual protein supplements?.

While buying them what should we be looking for? 
There are so many brands out there. Its a bit confusing.

Do testosterone pills help to increase mass gain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mass gainers are carbs + protein. Most of them use Maltodextrin a cheap and quickly digestible carbohydrate that's produced from starch. Considering that they are mostly starch the price per gram on commercial products is not good. Make your own higher quality gainer by adding to your protein shake a mix of bananas, instant-oats or canned chickpeas. A tbs of peanut butter will add some fat and pack on the protein unless you are going for a low-fat diet. Liquid Mass gainers are great for adding calories to your diet just remember to have them in addition to your regular meals instead of replacing them.